# Iterate line by line to get a beginning word and end word

Tags: python, list, multiple-columns

here's my code:

```
data = open("input.txt", "r") #list of everything in first column
first_word = []
for line in data:
    first_word.append(line.split(None,1)[0])
print(first_word)



data = open("input.txt", "r") #list of everything in second column 
last_word = []
for line in data:
    last_word.append(line.split(None, 2)[1])
print(last_word)
```

input.txt has two columns, first column contains the first word and second column contains the last words.

I'm able to get everything into a list by going row by row in each column but I want to get a new list that has [first_word, last_word]

here's where I'm having trouble

```
new_list = [first_word(line[0])+last_word(line[0])]
print(new_list)
```

error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: What's wrong with just `new_list = [first_word, last_word]`?

Comment: There's no need to read the file twice. use one loop that splits the line and appends each word into the appropriate list. `first, last = line.split()` then `first_word.append(first)` and `last_word.append(last)`

Comment: I just want the first index in first_word and the first index in last_word, then I want the second index in first_word and second index in last_word and so on until it goes through the entire column

Comment: That's not what "I want to get a new list that has [first_word, last_word]"` says.

Comment: Why did you put them in different lists in the first place? You could have done that when you were reading the file. `new_list.append(line.split())`

Comment: because I'm new to python and have no idea what I'm doing. I thought that taking the file and putting each column into separate lists would help but it didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[first_word[i],w] for i,w in enumerate(last_word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when reading the file in the first place, instead of appending each word to a different list.

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as data:
    new_list = [line.split() for line in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `zip()`

```
new_list = list(zip(first_word, last_word))
print(new_list)
```